# Rails 5 and AJAX, automatically submit Checkbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an index view with a lot of products. I want to add a checkbox for each product where the user can enable/disable each of them via AJAX.

So I did some reading and found out that there are some great Rails helpers: https://jonathanpike.net/2016/02/ajax-on-rails

So the code I cam up with is:

```
  <%= check_box_tag 'available', restaurant_product.id,
                data: {
                      remote: true,
                      url: restaurant_product_path(restaurant_product),
                      method: "PUT"
                }
   %>
```

I hoped that this would automatically make an AJAX request when the checkbox value ha been changed. But it does not. Can anybody help?

Comment: Compulsory u want checkbox ? I have solution for ur question but not check box instead button.

Comment: Post your controller and view.

Comment: Can you confirm you definitely don't see anything in your developer tool's network tab when toggling the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is: `check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`, you're missing one of them.

Try:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'available', restaurant_product.id, false,
               data: {
                     remote: true,
                     url: restaurant_product_path(restaurant_product),
                     method: "PUT"
               }
%>
```